# Necessary and sufficient conditions for Riemann integral of $f: E\subset \mathbb{R}^n \to E$ exists, where $E$ is and subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

In the book of *Mathematical Analysis II* by Zorich, at page 123, it is asked that

> Give necessary and sufficient conditions on a function $f : E →
>  \mathbb{R}$ defined on a bounded (but not necessarily
>   Jordan-measurable) set $E$ under which the Riemann integral of $f$
>   over $E$ exists.

My question is that, if $E$ is open, than would $f$ be discontinuous on $\partial E$ ? I mean $f$ is not even defined on $\partial E$, so I assume that it wouldn't, but then I recall the definition of Riemann integral over any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is

$$\int_T f *dx := \int_{T \subset I}f *\gamma_T (x)* dx, \quad where \quad \gamma_T (x) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & x \in T\\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}\quad and \quad I \text{ is any interval containing $E$}$$
and Zorich points out $\int_{T \subset I} \gamma_T (x)* dx$ is defined only for sets $T$ whose boundary is measure zero since $\gamma_T(x)$ has discontinuities on $\partial T$.

Therefore, I'm sort of confused because $\gamma_T$ is defined on the boundary of $E$, but $f$ is not.

I mean even if we (somehow) say that $f$ is discontinues on $\partial E$, then $\partial E$ has to be Jordan measure zero and $int (E)$ has to be Lebesgue measure zero, right ?

**Edit:** For additional questions, please see the comments on the given answer.

Comment: How does the textbook define the Riemann integral of $f$ on $E$ if $E$ is not a compact rectangle? Is it done by extending $f$ outside $E$ by setting $ f \equiv 0$ on $E^c$ and considering the Riemann integral of the extension on a compact rectangle containing $E$?

Comment: @SangchulLee See my edit. Plus, Riemann integral of $f$ over an **interval** is defined as the limit of Riemann sum $f$.

Comment: @Dap Thanks for pointing out, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function $f$ is Riemann integrable on a bounded rectangle $Q$ if and only if it is bounded and the set of discontinuity points is of measure $0$.

On a bounded set $E$ the integral exists when $f \chi_E$ is integrable over any rectangle $Q$ with $E \subset Q$ and is given by $\int_E f = \int_Q f \chi_E$.

Necessary and sufficient conditions are $f$ is almost everwhere continuous in $E$  and either $\partial E$ is of measure $0$ or $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to p$ for all points $p \in \partial E$ except perhaps in a subset of $\partial E$ of measure $0$.  This second condition takes care of the case where $m(\partial E) \neq 0$.

Comment: but $f$ is not defined on $\partial E$ if $E$ is not closed.

Comment: No, but $f \chi_E$ is  and the integral is defined in terms of $\int_Q f \chi_E$.

Comment: Even if $f$ is not defined on the boundary it can approach a limit from inside.

Comment: Yes it can do that, but I guess we can argue that the continuity of $f$ implies that the limit of $f$ while it is approaching to the boundary is equal to the value of the function on that boundary point, but $f$ is not defined on the boundary, hence it cannot be discontinuous (since the premise is false). Moreover, $\chi_E$ is discontinues on $\partial E$, hence the product $f \chi_E$ is discontinuous on $\partial E$, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes -- $\chi_E$ is discontinuous on $\partial E$. So if $f(x) = 1$ in $E$ then $f\chi_E = \chi_E$ is not integrable unless $\partial E$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Suppose $m(\partial E) \neq 0$.  Then $f(x) \chi_E(x) = 0 \to 0$ as $x $ approaches a boundary point from outside $E$.  If it so happens that $f(x) = f(x) \chi_E(x) \to 0$ as $x$ approaches a boundary point from inside $E$, then that is the only possible way for $f\chi_E$ to be continuous on the boundary and , hence integrable.  It could happen and it only need happen except perhaps on a measure $0$ subset of the boundary.

Comment: You are saying that $\partial E$ has **Lebesgue** measure zero, right ?

Comment: You are saying that if $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to p \in \partial E$ then it means that $f$ is defined on the boundary.  But the theorem only has as a hypothesis that $f$ is defined on $E$.  Thus it must be extendable to the boundary to be integrable -- and it has to be extendable to the value $0$ if $\partial E$ is not a Jordan boundary.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that, I have never said anything about $f(x) \to 0$.I'm just saying that since $f(p)$ for $p \in \partial E$ is not defined, it has to be continuous on $\partial$ because the premise in the definition of continuity is false, hence the statement is true tautologically.

Comment: Lebesgue measure zero or content zero.

Comment: How  ? $\chi_E$ is already zero and discontinuous on the boundary of $E$

Comment: Lets be perfectly clear.  Say $E$ is open and $m(\partial E) \neq 0$. For $f$ to be integrable on $E$ we need $f\chi_E$ to be integrable on the rectangle that contains $E \cup \partial E$.  That can only happen if $f \chi_E$ is continuous at almost every point in $\partial E$.  In this case as you say $f \chi_E = 0$ on the boundary since $\chi_E = 0$ there.  So how can we make $f \chi_E$ continuous on the boundary?  -- the only possible way that $f \chi_E$ is integrable on $Q$ in this case.  What do you think?  Are you saying its impossible?

Comment: There is only one way -- $f$ has to be extendable as a continuous function on $E \cup \partial E$ only  taking zero values on the boundary.  That is all we are saying here.  A non-zero measure boundary is already rare -- so there is only a very restricted class of functions that can be integrable on an open set with such a boundary.  We know there is at least one function --  $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in E$ -- and this requires no definition of $f$ on the boundary.

Comment: What is $Q$ in your first comment ?

Comment: Plus, why is the only way for $f \chi_E$ be continuous that if it integrable on $Q$ (whatever the Q is)  ?

Comment: Moreover, why can f only be extended to a continuous function on $E \cup \partial E$ by taking the zero values on the boundary ?

Comment: (1) $Q$ is the enclosing bounded rectangle (or interval).  It is the same as what you call  $I$ in your question. We have the Riemann integrability condition that says $f \chi_E$ is continuous on $Q$ (except possibly on a subset of measure $0$) if and only if it is Riemann integrable over $Q$.  Note "if and only if". (3)  $f$ can be extended to a continuous function on the boundary with non-zero values, but if $f \chi_E$ is to be integrable when $m(\partial E) \neq 0$ then those values have to be zero.

Comment: Ok, after reading your answer with a clear mind, I understood. Thanks a lot both for your answer and your effort to explain your answer.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: You're welcome.